Azure Cognitive Search boost boolean field
I'm looking to boost results where a boolean field is true.  I have a scoring profile set up for my string values which works great. However, I've not found a way to boost if the boolean field has a true value in the scoring profile or outside of the scoring profile. I've tried adding it in the search parameter like so:
mysearchterm OR (mysearchterm AND resultisfeatured:(true))^2
and it returns odd results and does not boost those results any higher.

The search query you are doing only works on the fields which is Searchable, but your field resultisfeatured is of Boolean type and it is not searchable only it can be

Retrievable
Filterable
Sortable
Facetable

Refer this stack solution regarding this.
If you try to add new field of Boolean type you can see below you cannot configure add searchable attribute.

So, possible solution is

Re build the index adding Sortable attribute to your boolean field and do sorting so that true values will be on top.

Here, is the sample Json query I used to my data
{
  "search": "HotelName:Countryside",
  "orderby": "ParkingIncluded desc",
  "select": "HotelName,ParkingIncluded"
}

Output:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xxxxxx.search.windows.net/indexes('hotels-sample-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.9433406,
      "HotelName": "Countryside Resort",
      "ParkingIncluded": true
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 1.192267,
      "HotelName": "Countryside Hotel",
      "ParkingIncluded": false
    }
  ]
}

In you case the search query will be something like below.
{
  "search": "mysearchterm",
  "orderby": "resultisfeatured desc"
}


Or you can create new field of type string with searchable attribute.

Then do full query search like below.
{
  "search": "HotelName:Countryside OR (HotelName:Countryside AND ParkingincludedString:(true))^2",
  "select": "HotelName,ParkingincludedString",
  "queryType": "full"
}

And output
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.search.windows.net/indexes('hotels-sample-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 3.770029,
      "HotelName": "Countryside Resort",
      "ParkingincludedString": "true"
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 1.192267,
      "HotelName": "Countryside Hotel",
      "ParkingincludedString": "false"
    }
  ]
}

If you see the ParkingincludedString is the new field created and it is boosted the score.
To create new field you need a conditional skill set which takes Boolean input and return string values based on the values, follow below steps to create.
First create a field in index.

then give a name, type and attribute like below.

Create a ConditionalSkill set and add it in indexer.
Below is the Json definition of skillset.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xxxx.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCB5E81E4F3DF5\"",
  "name": "skillset1722928484642",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ConditionalSkill",
      "name": "check1",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "condition",
          "source": "= $(/document/ParkingIncluded)" #YourBooleanField
        },
        {
          "name": "whenTrue",
          "source": "= 'true'"
        },
        {
          "name": "whenFalse",
          "source": "= 'false'"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "output",
          "targetName": "parkingskillout"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Json definition of indexer.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsaiservice.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCB5E8A85A3360\"",
  "name": "hotels-sample-indexer2",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "hotels-sample",
  "skillsetName": "skillset1722928484642",
  "targetIndexName": "hotels-sample-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": false,
    "configuration": {}
  },
  "fieldMappings": [],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/parkingskillout",
      "targetFieldName": "ParkingincludedString" #YourFieldInIndex
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Here, in outputFieldMappings i mapped output of skillset to index field ParkingincludedString
Next, reset and rerun the indexer to perform query search.

